# Azure Pipelines GitHub Packages Don't Work

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, github-package-registry

Following the instructions here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2020/pipelines/sprint-170-update

Have the following:

```
  packages:
  - package: MyPkg
    type: NuGet
    connection: github
    name: TheOrg/TheRepo/ThePkg
    version: '*'
```

and

```
    - getPackage: MyPkg
```

Azure Pipelines doesn't seem to get this even remotely correct. I'm not sure how this would have even passed basic testing.

The logs show:

```
Using authentication information for the following URI: https://nuget.pkg.github.com/{ThePATUser}/index.json
```

Well that's just wrong...I specified an organization. The user that generated the PAT is not the NuGet feed I'm trying to consume

And then

```
"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" add d:\a\1\Nuget\dotnet\tempCsproj_67.csproj package TheRepo -v * -n
```

That's clearly just wrong too. Does this feature actually work at all?

I looked at the source code for the task:
https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/pull/12292/files#diff-6aadc4d5fa0b434a99fe35ba9d3d2ac4R55

and from what I can tell this is just bad logic. Would appreciate confirmation from someone at MS that this code is indeed non-functional.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the same issue. The github package failed to be retrieved using the `getPackage` step. The feed url is evaluated to the PAT User feed url rather than the organization feed url.

You can click [this link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/post.html?space=21) to report this issue to Microsoft development team. Hope they will look into this issue and provide a fix soon!